# Is there an RSS / ATOM feed for new questions?

Tags: sffaq

Is there an RSS / ATOM feed for new questions?

There is a feed on StackOverflow that is really useful.  Is there an equivalent on SeverFault?

Sorry if this is a duplicate or already in the FAQ but I couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried https://serverfault.com/feeds for the "recent questions feed" which you can find on the bottom of the home-page?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Where is the feed linked from?  I couldn't find it anywhere on the site or am I just blind?

Comment: Thanks.  I was spending too much time on the questions page :)

Answer (score 0):

When your on the main page (eg: no a question) its displayed in the bottom right corner in either text form or a orange square.